# inverse Jacobi Elliptic Function with Complex arguments

Tags: elliptic-functions

I need to find the inverse of Jacobi Elliptic function that has a complex argument. I know how to calculate the Jacobi Elliptic function with complex input but I have not seen any formula or MATLAB/python functions that can calculate the inverse Jacobi Elliptic function that has complex arguments.

If anyone knows how to calculate this, please give me some suggestions.

Thank you.
Khalid

Comment: What Jacobi Elliptic Function? Please be more specific and try to add the more details possible, including writing down equations and so on.

Comment: Big hint: all the inverses may be expressed as $\operatorname{pq}^{-1}(y,k)=F(f(y,k),k)$ for some function $f$ of $y$ and $k$.